# How do I limit 'has many' row entries returned by a date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class for a child

```
class Child < BaseModel
  attr_protected

  has_many :child_parent_relationships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :child_daycare_relationships, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :child_class_relationships, :dependent => :destroy

  has_many :parent_users, :through => :child_parent_relationships


  has_many :attendance_records

  has_many :moods
  has_many :behaviors

  validates :first_name, :presence => true


end
```

When I get the child Child.find(id) it returns all of the has_many relations.   How do I return the child but then limit the relations of say the mood table by a field value like date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this a couple ways.

If you have a child variable

```
@child = Child.find(id)
```

You can add scopes to Mood and Behaviors, or where clauses. So you ask for something like

```
@child.moods.where(field: "value")
```

or

```
class Behavior < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :filtered, -> { where(field: "value") }

end

# Use scopes like so
@child.behaviors.filterd
```

To use a date in a scope, it would be something like this

```
scope :on_date, -> (date) { where field: date }
scope :before_date, -> (date) { where("behaviors.field < ?", date) }
```

you can also set up has many relationships to prefilter

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :specific_moods, -> { where(field: "value" }, class_name: "Mood"
  has_many :certain_behaviors, -> { where(field: "value" }, class_name: "Behavior"

end
```

Then you can use this in your views:

```
@child.specific_moods
@child.certain_behaviors
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  The prefilter option you suggest looks like it would work best for me.   I am new to ruby on rails and inheriting a project but it looks amazing so far... just trying to wrap my head around it

Comment: One other question.... is there a way to pass through a parameter to the prefiltered ones like if I pass a certain date for a date field?

Comment: In that case you'd want to use a scope.  I updated the answer to include some details.  If you're doing date equality comparisons, you may need to do a little work to make sure you're only comparing dates (not times).

Answer (score 0):

Just append the conditions you need.

```
Child.find(id).moods.where(field: "value")
```

Comment: great could I append several like if I wanted to limit both moods and behaviors?

Comment: Child.find(id).moods.where(field: "value").behaviors.where(field: "value")